# writing files at a low level

Tags: c, low-level-io

I was reading the GNU C PROGRAMMING TUTORIAL online, and get some confusion on the code example for low level read & write.

The code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  char my_write_str[] = "1234567890";
  char my_read_str[100];
  char my_filename[] = "snazzyjazz.txt";
  int my_file_descriptor, close_err;

  /* Open the file.  Clobber it if it exists. */
  my_file_descriptor = open (my_filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);

 /* Write 10 bytes of data and make sure it's written */
 write (my_file_descriptor, (void *) my_write_str, 10);
 fsync (my_file_descriptor);

 /* Seek the beginning of the file */
 lseek (my_file_descriptor, 0, SEEK_SET);

 /* Read 10 bytes of data */
 read (my_file_descriptor, (void *) my_read_str, 10);

 /* Terminate the data we've read with a null character */
 my_read_str[10] = '\0';

 printf ("String read = %s.\n", my_read_str);

 close (my_file_descriptor);

 return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code with gcc without issue. And run the first time, it is also ok. Output as below:

```
$ ./lowLevelWrite
String read = 1234567890.
```

The problem comes when i run the program second time:

```
$ ./lowLevelWrite
String read = .
```

Seems the code fails to write the string "1234567890" to the file second time. As we know from the GNU C manual, `O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC` these flag should allow us to truncate the file to 0 every time and then write to the file. I am not sure why it fails from second time execution.

Can anybody help me out of this confusion?

Comment: Most likely, the file is created without enough permissions that would allow you to overwrite the file if it already exists.  Check the return code from open, and I bet that you'll see it's returning -1 instead of a valid file handle.

Comment: If the tutorial you are using really omits all error handling, you should stop using it immediately. Such a tutorial is irresponsible.

Comment: `ls -l snazzyjazz.txt` would be quite informative as to why this is occurring.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this, my dear friend. I love stackoverflow, all question can find a answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're creating a file with `open()` you need to pass a third argument, the permission modes:

```
my_file_descriptor = open (my_filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0664);
```

`0664` is the permissions `rw-rw-r--`: readable and writable by the owner and group, readable by everyone else. These permissions will be further masked by your `umask`.

Since you didn't pass this argument, `open()` used random stack garbage, and this probably didn't include write permission. So you couldn't open the file for writing when it already exists.